# ejs@3.1.3 postinstall: `node --harmony ./postinstall.js Exit status 1

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs

While I'm trying to install `ejs` using `npm` I'm getting this error and I'm not able to install `ejs` in my PC. can anyone help me with this?

[image: Error consisting image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything available in Google and finally, I got the solution `npm install ejs --force` by this command we can install `ejs` forcibly to your project.